# SQLMAP --eval parameter, base64 a parameter containing hyphens

Tags: python, sqlmap

As suggested here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165528/sqlmap-eval-parameter-base64-a-parameter-containing-hyphens?noredirect=1#comment314635_165528 I move my question on Stack Overflow.
Just got a problem trying to use the --eval function of sqlmap.I need to convert a get parameter (test-parameter) in base64 for each new payload. When I try using the --eval function like:

```
--eval="test-parameter=test-parameter.encode('base64')"
```

Python gives me an error, probably because you cannot use variable name containing hyphens.

Anybody has a solution?